# how to execute data from tabular to form in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am creating Project about school management system

I want when double click mouse on tabular data then show data in form

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `WHEN-MOUSE-DOUBLECLICK` trigger?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand,
you have created a form with master - detail relation, and when you double-click on one of the records of master part( lower one with **SCHOOL DATA** title ), want to see the results in the upper part( with **SCHOOL** title ) for matching `school_id` columns. By the way, I assume `school_id` column has unique values for each record.

So,

From the `Data Blocks` node choose `blk_school` ( the block whose items are located inside the frame `SCHOOL` ), and set `WHERE` property ( in the `Database Node` of `Property Palette` ) to the value of

```
school_id = :blk_school_data.school_id
```

where `blk_school_data` is the block whose items are located inside the frame `SCHOOL DATA`. And then, create a `WHEN-MOUSE-DOUBLECLICK` trigger for the block `blk_school_data` with the code :

```
go_block('blk_school');
clear_block(no_validate);
execute_query;
```

to bring data whenever any of the items from lower block is double-clicked.

Comment: I have 3 records in data when i click on 3rd data then show 1st data. I want to show specific data when double click

Comment: I have 3 records in data when i click on 3rd data then show 1st data. I want to show specific data when double click

Comment: @RamizTariq Did you double-click on the upper (frame titled as `SCHOOL`) frame or the lower(frame titled as `SCHOOL DATA`) frame? Do both frame depend on the same table ..?

Comment: I want to show data from tabular (school data) to form (school)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan your answer is correct. I just follow your steps and it works for me as well. I was sreaching for this for 1 day, finally you give me the right answer. thanks a lot. upvote. And Ramiz Tariq should mark this answer.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I think its better you create where clause in that trigger as this   
       `v_where := 'id_ser=' || :main_data1.id_ser1;`
       `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('main_data', default_where, v_where);`

Answer (score 0):

That layout doesn't make any sense. Both tabular and form block display *exactly* same data (ID, name & address), so - what's the point in that?

Furthermore, if this is a master-detail (at least, it looks like that), then you got it wrong - in order for detail data to be displayed, master must exist. You can't fetch detail records without their master, so - how do you plan to double-click on something that doesn't exist? I'm not saying that it is *impossible*, but requires additional programming (i.e. modifying block(s) properties), and I'm not sure that this is what you want.

Perhaps you should consider creating a single tabular block that contains all columns you're interested in, so you could query everything you want in a single form. Its source would be a view (created as join of master and detail tables), or a FROM clause (it'd have the same join as the view). Note that - if you need to enable updating - you might need to create INSTEAD OF (database) trigger(s), create additional form triggers (such as ON-UPDATE, PRE-UPDATE, and such), and all of that makes things more complex than they should be.

So, if you could explain what *real* problem you're trying to solve (instead of a *fabricated* one, as displayed on the screenshot you attached), it would be easier to assist.